# Is there any affiliation with SkillTrainingComplete.com?

Tags: discussion

I recently stumbled across http://skilltrainingcomplete.com.  Obviously, it looks like it's using the same engine as the Stack Exchange sites, or is doing a very good job of imitating it.  It doesn't look like it's connected with Stack Exchange at all, though.

It says the engine it uses is [Shapado](http://shapado.com/pages/code).  What's the affiliation here?

Comment: I think it's one of those stack exchange 1.0 sites that had to switch to something else

Comment: Tangentially related, but if you see sites that mass-copy our content, make sure they're [doing it right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24611/) and complain otherwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None whatsoever. Shapado is not the same engine as StackExchange, it's a clone.

Basically, people decided they wanted their own website like StackExchange but control it themselves, so they built [open-source engines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953) based on it which you can host yourself.

As such, they seem similar, but there is in fact no affiliation at all between them and us.

Comment: I can't edit yet, but you could put a link to the "clones" post on mso http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones/37953#37953

Comment: @davidsleeps Added that in, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I'm the admin of Skill Training Complete. We were originally a StackExchange site but were unable to get the following required to survive the proposal process so I moved to Shapado so that the community could continue.